# Devise issue, unable to sign in or sign out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, turbo-frames

I have:
// app/javascript/application.js

import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
Turbo.session.drive = true

But when i try to sign in /sign out I get:
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#new
match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super

But when i change it to "false", Devise is fine, but the site will not recognize anything related to Turbo or JS within the site.

Comment: Which version of Devise are you currently using?

Comment: gem 'devise', '~> 4.9', '>= 4.9.2'

Comment: i may have to go back to devise 4.8

Comment: i switched back to 4.8 and i stll get -         match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super

Comment: Have you gone through the upgrade guide for Devise 4.9? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Upgrade-to-Devise-4.9.0-%5BHotwire-Turbo-integration%5D

Comment: i udated to Devise 4.9 correctly this time and it works. thanks

Comment: That's great news!